# exit function doesn't do what I expected

Tags: c

So after I execute my code it won't exit it, so I thought I should add the exit function at the end but it still doesn't exit the program.

```
  if(bclass)
  {
 if(d==0) printf("Scanez %d.%d.%d.*\n",a,b,c);
 d++;
 if(d>255)
 {
  c++;d=0;
 }
 sprintf(ip,"%d.%d.%d.%d",a,b,c,d);
 if((c==255) && (d==255))                                                           {
  printf("%s\n",ip);                                                                 printf("[+] Scanarea s-a incheiat cu succes!\n");
  sleep(10);
  kill(pid,2);
  exit(0);
  return 0;
 }
 sc.s_addr=inet_addr(ip);
 dstip=sc.s_addr;
  }
```

Comment: Please make an effort and format your code correctly.

Comment: Also make it complete. Like in [mcve]. Anyway, having anything after `return` statement is pointless.

Comment: `exit(0);` will never be executed, because it comes _after_  the `return 0;`. The problem is elsewhere in the code you didn't post. Pleasse show a [mcve]

Comment: `return` does not set a return code, but terminates the function returning in your code a 0 value. I guess you want it to get to `exit(0);`?

Comment: There's no loop here, so there's no reason the code shouldn't exit.  A [mcve] would help with your actual problem.

Comment: @dbush I don't know what else from the code to post. If you want I can show you the entire code.

Comment: @Richardmikelson You need to post something that others can copy/paste *as is*, compile, and run that reproduces your problem.  Not necessarily *all* your code however.  That's the "minimal" part of a MCVE.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/hv7AcV30

Comment: Whole program in `main` (260 lines)... classy

Comment: This isn't a crowdsourced debugging service

Comment: @M.M so what do you suggest?

Comment: I suggest posting a MCVE

Answer (score 1):

As other suggested you should read [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Now to explain problems in your code.

First thing is your whole code. If it is not in `main()` function then `return 0;` will not exit program but return `0` from the method.

Method that would exit your program is `exit(0);` but it is never executed since it is after `return`

If up code IS inside `main()` it is still possible it would reach `return 0` part since it is inside `if((c==255) && (d==255))`, so if it doesn't meet that condition, your code will not reach `return`

Comment: The code is inside main(). I've put the exit(0); before the return 0; and the program still doesn't closes. I also edited the post with 3 lines I forgot about.

Comment: Read last part of answer. It is inside `if` part. what `if(doesn't meet condition)`, where is your return/exit?